# Compare value to items in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list of calendar days for 500 years starting in 2000 without the use of datetime or calendar functions but I'm having trouble iterating through the DaysinMonth list correctly. I set the initial day, month, year, now want iterate and append new values to a set of arrays.

```py
for i in range(len(centday)):
    #if month value is less than 12, the year value= year. If it is 13, add one to the year value. 
    if month <= 12:
        year = year
        yearar.append(year)
    else: 
        year += 1
        yearar.append(year)
        
    #If year is a leap year, change the number of days in months accordingly    
    if year%4 == 0:
        DaysinMonth= [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    else:
        DaysinMonth= [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    
    #set item value    
    j = month - 1  
    listlength = len(DaysinMonth)
    i=0
    if i < listlength:
        if day <= DaysinMonth[i]:
            day = day 
            dayar.append(day)
            monthar.append(month)
        else:
            day = 1
            month += 1
            monthar.append(month)
            i += 1
            if month > 12:
                month = 1
                i = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

@dominicm00 has a good answer based on the immediate question. But if this problem is anything more than academic, consider using this solution as it's more maintainable.

## Solution

Let python's `datetime` handle datetime business logic.

### Example

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

result = []

start_date = date(2000, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2500, 12, 31)
delta = end_date - start_date

for days in range(delta.days + 1):
    date_ = start_date + timedelta(days=days)
    
    result.append(date_.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

## Note

Working with datetime objects are a bit more expensive—space and time-wise—especially when working with large deltas and more granular units (ie: hours) than calculating the datetimes  yourself. In the end, the solution you choose depends on whether you're optimizing for performance or maintainability.

Also, you may find something worth using in python's calendar library:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/85339f5c220a5e79c47c3a33c93f1dca5c59c52e/Lib/calendar.py

## References

date, timedelta: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the complexity in your solution comes from attempting to use only one `for` loop. If you have nested loops for year > month > day, it'll be much easier to work with:

```py
dates = []
start_year = 2000
end_year = 2500

for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        days_in_month = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    else:
        days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

    for month in range(1, len(days_in_month) + 1)):
        for day in range(1, days_in_month[month] + 1):
            # here we create a date
            dates.append(f"{year}/{month}/{day}")
```

**Note:** I'm assuming this is some sort of problem due to the constraint to not use datetime or calendar functions, but just in case know that there's a lot of funkiness with dates beyond leap years and month lengths. If you encounter a situation where you need to know your dates are correct, please use a date library as they are designed to deal with all the edge cases that can arise.